# require js backbone js jquery template markup rely

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have an ***underscore JS*** template and a **jQuery plug-in** that depends on the markup that gets rendered after the template is visible, but the problem is when I use **jQuery** document ready, it doesn't get the HTML that is rendered.

I used `domReady` but still ain't working, how can I accomplish this probably? This is what I got so far:

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/modules',
    shim: {
        // 'jquery.colorize': ['jquery'],
        // 'jquery.scroll': {
        //  deps: ['jquery'],
        //  exports: 'jQuery.fn.colorize'
        // },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '_'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../libs/jquery',
        'underscore': '../libs/underscore',
        'backbone': '../libs/backbone',
        'text': '../libs/text',
        'views': '../views',
        'templates': '../../templates',
        'domReady': '../libs/domReady',
        'ui': '../ui'
    }
});

requirejs(['homeView', 'ui/placeholder'], function(Main){
    Main.initialize();
});
```

**homeView.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/home.html'], function($, _, Backbone, homeTemplate){
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#application"),
        events: function(){
            // Empty.
        },
        initialize: function(){
            // Empty.
        },
        render: function(){
            $('body').addClass('pt-dark');
            $(this.el).html(_.template(homeTemplate, {}));
        }
    });

    return new HomeView;
});
```

**ui/placeholder.js**

```
requirejs(['domReady', 'jquery'], function(doc, $){
  doc(function(){
    // Empty should contain the template html at this point.
    console.log($('body').html()); 
  });
});
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Any particular reason you can't do this in your homeView.render(), or have that fire off a call to this other plugin?  It isn't working because you have a race going on between domReady and when homeView.render() is actually inserting your html.

Comment: @radicand I use data-api elements, so the jQuery plugin requires the template content, this has to be possible right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/home.html'], function($, _, Backbone, homeTemplate){
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#application"),
        template: _.template(homeTemplate),
        events: function(){
            // Empty.
        },
        initialize: function(){
            // Empty.
        },
        render: function(){
            $('body').addClass('pt-dark');
            this.$el.html(this.template({})));
            jQuery('#the_thing_you_need', this.$el).theFunctionYouNeed();
        }
    });

    return new HomeView;
});
```

Note that you should define a local attribute to the view called 'template' or something of that sort to store your template in and not re-call _.template every time that you need it.

Also, instead of jQuery(this.el) you can use this.$el.